# Edges in java methods

Tags: java

Edge.java:

```
public interface Edge {
    public Node getFirstNode();
    public Node getSecondNode();
}
```

EdgeImpl.java

```
public class EdgeImpl implements Edge {

    @Override
    public Node getFirstNode() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Node getSecondNode() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The methods are:

`getFirstNode` returns the first node in the edge.

`getSecondNode` returns the second node in the edge.

`EdgeImpl.java` implements the interface `Edge.java`. This implementation takes into consideration all features found in the interface.

I'm confused on what the constructors should be. Could anyone assist me on that? I made a `Node` class first unsure if its needed.

Comment: What you really want to do, which data structure do you want to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
public class EdgeImpl implements Edge {
  private Node firstNode;
  private Node secondNode;

  public EdgeImpl(Node firstNode, Node secondNode) {
    this.firstNode = firstNode;
    this.secondNode = secondNode;
  }

  @Override
  public Node getFirstNode() {
    return firstNode;
  }

  @Override
  public Node getSecondNode() {
    return secondNode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two instance variables :

```
private Node firstNode;
private Node secondNode;
```

Then you can have a constructor:

```
public EdgeImpl(Node firstNode, Node secondNode) {
    this.firstNode = firstNode;
    this.secondNode = secondNode;
}
```